# mongodb 3 MONGODB-CR authentication

Tags: mongodb

Is it possibile to create Users with the old MONGODB-CR User authentication in mongo 3.0.2?

Actually I've only one User created by default with the new SCRAM-SHA-1 credential authentication.

```
 db.system.users.find({ "credentials.SCRAM-SHA-1" : { $exists: true}}, { user: 1, db: 1})

{ "_id" : "admin.siteUserAdmin", "user" : "siteUserAdmin", "db" : "admin" }
```

and:

```
 db.system.users.find({ "credentials.MONGODB-CR" : { $exists: true}}, { user: 1, db: 1})
```

is empty.

Comment: SCRAM-SHA1 only. It was kind of the point. And why you are asked to update this in many guides that are available.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
```

(from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17459)